# jQuery find() unable to find object

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery
I am firing an event in a column within a table that contains a drop down like below:

```
$(document).on('change','#DropDown',function(){
var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');       
var photoID = tr.find('#id').val();
}
```

I have the following HTML:

```
 <table class="grid">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span id="1">1</span>
</td>
```

I want to retrieve the value 1 and store it into photoID but i am unable to find it.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: there is no element with id `id`?

Comment: where is the dropdown which triggers the change

Comment: when you're using `$(this)` you're saying this = #dropdown.  It wont find something that's not there.  Can you show us where your dropdown is?

Comment: your javascript and html are not matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(document).on('change','#DropDown',function(){
  var tr = $(this).parents('tr');       
  var photoID = tr.find('span').attr('id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$(document).on('change','#DropDown',function(){
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');       
    var photoID = tr.find('span').id;
}
```